# PHP global variable problem accross multiple files

Tags: php, variables, global

so I have site structure like this. I have `index.php`, that includes() `include.php`, which includes `functions.php` and a bunch of other files.
What I want to do is write `$GLOBALS["something"] = 'something here';` in `functions.php` and after do `echo $something;` in `index.php` so it would print `something here`, but for some reason it returns nothing. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Try to print $GLOBALS with vardump and post the output.

Comment: Post some actual code and we'll be able to help more easily.

Comment: Write clean code, instead of using global variables.

Comment: @leo what exactly I should post from $GLOBALS? There are about few hundred of variables there.

Comment: @Michael there are a lot of functions that does not have anything to do with this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `index.php` you either have to say `echo $GLOBALS['something']` or `global $something; echo $something;` in order to register `$something` as a global variable.

However, I would discourage using global variables at all and instead use constants if you have to.

Comment: that`s what I tried, but echo $GLOBALS['something'] still output nothing. I appreciate your advice about constants, but I`ll stick to globals now.

Comment: @Treat: Are you sure the files are included and the globals registered before the code using them is called?

Comment: @NikiC when you asked it like that, I understood that the globals are defined in a function and moved them outside a function and now they give output in index.php. Is there a way to define them in function and still get an output in index.php?

Comment: I am sure that you have checked http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @mozillanerd yup actually it was open in other tab, when i read your post. So I tried many ways, ex: function hey() { global $something; $something == "something here"; } and i echo`ed $something in index.php and it didn`t show anything. I also tried with $GLOBALS, also nothing. Can you please tell me where the mistake is or give me a better example than in php.net?